# Calculating the flux of the vector field + Gauss

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Calculate the flux $\int_BF · ν dS$ of the vector field $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, F(x, y, z) := (yz, xz, x^2)^T$ through the northern hemisphere B of radius 1 with 0 as its center, i.e. the surface
> $B := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, z > 0\}$

This is what I got so far:

$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

$vdS=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1)$

$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2}(yz, xz, x^2)*vdS\;dydx$

$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} y\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, x^2 (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1) \ dy\ dx\\
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} x^2+2xy\; dy dx\\
\int_{-1}^1  2x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} dx\\
\frac\pi 2*\frac1 4(\frac\pi 2 * \frac1 4) = \frac \pi 4$

**EDIT:** I replaced the last two lines, but for some reason the answer doesn't match the one given in this post, which I am sure is correct, so if anyone sees my mistake and can kindly point it out, it would be great! **found**

Is this correct? And I also want to know how can I calculate using the following steps:

(i) Draw B and find an embedding of B.

(ii) Identify the outer normal vector ν on B.

(iii) Finally, calculate $\int_BF · ν dS.$

What do the first two steps add if I can calculate the flux directly?

I thank anyone who can help!

**EDIT.NR2** : If I use Gauss theorem to find the flux is it possible for it to be different?

Comment: @user170231 I added another line to explain what I was doing there and I checked it again, but I am getting the same answer

Comment: There should be square roots in the integral wrt $y$. Namely,$$\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} f(x) \, dy = 2\sqrt{1-x^2}\,f(x)$$

Comment: I got it now, thanks

Comment: Perhaps you know what does it mean to draw B? I'm not sure how am I supposed to draw this: $x^2+y^2+z+^2=1, z>0 $

Comment: As the text says, $B$ is a hemisphere, easy to visualize and draw (no doubt your textbook, if you have one, shows at least one example, and if not, you can look it up online). I believe "embedding" in this case refers to the region over which you ultimately integrate, i.e. the "shadow" of the hemisphere above the $x,y$ plane.

Comment: What is a shadow of the hemisphere? how and where I need to put it? Its just the first time I am hearing about this so I have no idea what is going on

Comment: I suggest looking over [these examples](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx). The first graphic depicts exactly what I'm talking about - if you were to shine a light directly above the surface $S$, it would cast the shadow $D$ below it.

Comment: so the shadow is the bounds of x and y?

Comment: Yes. In other words, the disk $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\le1\}$ is the embedding of the hemisphere $B$ in the plane $z=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using spherical coordinates

$ \hat{n} dS = ( \sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta) \sin \theta \ d\theta \ d \phi $

$ \vec{F} = ( \sin \theta \cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi, \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi ) $

So

$ \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS = (\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \phi + \sin^2 \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \phi + \sin^2 \theta \cos \theta \cos^2 \phi ) \sin \theta \ d\theta \ d\phi$

And this simplifies to

$ \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS = \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta (\sin(2 \phi) + \cos^2(\phi) ) \ d\theta \ d\phi$

Integrating with respect to $\phi$ first, from $\phi = 0 $ to $\phi = 2 \pi$, we get the term $\sin(2 \phi) $ cancelled out, and the term $\cos^2 \phi$ contributing a fator of $ \pi $

i.e.

$\displaystyle \int_B \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS = \pi \int_{\theta = 0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta \ d\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: ooooh I completely forgot about trigonomeric substitution, thank you

Comment: Is this with the step where  need to identify the outer normal vector ν on B?

Comment: If we don't do the trigonometric substitutions at first would the outer normal vector be $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1)$ ?

Comment: No, it would be $\hat{n} = (x, y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} ) $

Comment: Actually, if you include $dS$ in the outer normal, then $\hat{n} dS = (\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}}, \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}} , 1 ) dx dy $ as you said.

Comment: Why when calculating without using trigonometric substitutions am I getting $\fracπ 8$?

Comment: I don't know why.  Can you write what you have done in the body of your question as your attempt, and I'll try and see where the mistake is.

Comment: I think I found your mistake, you're integrating from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$.  You should integrate from $x = -1 $ to $x = 1 $.

Comment: Oh, yeah that seem to be the mistake, if it is not too much to ask, how did you get -1 and 1?

Comment: The base of the hemisphere is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so the range of $x$ is from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: oooooooooooh okay thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Part (i) is probably to familiarize yourself with visualizing surfaces. In the figure, $B$ is the transparent hemisphere (orange) and its embedding in the $(x,y)$ plane is the ruled disk shown in the plane $z=0$ (light blue).

[image]

Part (ii) is a necessary step in computing the surface integral because the surface element $d\vec S$ depends on the normal vector. But when it comes to computing the normal to $B$, you can choose either $\vec s_u\times \vec s_v$ or $\vec s_v\times\vec s_u$, where $\vec s(u,v)$ is a vector-valued function that parameterizes $B$. Your choice affects the sign of the surface element and integral. The figure from part (i) can help decide which is the correct choice.

---

And yes, you can confirm your result with Gauss' theorem.

Note that the theorem applies to *closed* surfaces, and $B$ is *not* closed. So suppose we close it up by connecting to $B$ a simple region, say, the disk $D:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\le1\}$. Now apply the theorem to $B\cup D$:

$$\iint_{B\cup D} \vec F\cdot \vec\nu\,d\vec S = \iiint_{\operatorname{int}(B\cup D)} \underbrace{\nabla\cdot \vec F}_{=0} \, dV = 0$$

which means $\iint_B=-\iint_D$. In the region $D$, we have $\vec F=\langle0,0,x^2\rangle$ and the outer normal is $\vec\nu=\langle0,0,-1\rangle$, so the flux across $D$ is

$$\iint_D \vec F\cdot\vec\nu \, d\vec S = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \langle0,0,x^2\rangle\cdot\langle0,0,-1\rangle\,dy\,dx$$

and multiplying by $-1$ makes this agree with your integral.